# 2 Listboxes into 1 and then delete matching values VBA

Tags: vba, listbox, match

I want to have 2 listboxes, 1 with a bunch of values and one with another bunch of values, I want to add them to a 3rd listbox and then delete all of the matching values,

here is my code i have got so far,

```
   For i = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
ListBox3.AddItem (ListBox1.List(i))
Next

Dim qstring As String


For i = 0 To (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)

qstring = ListBox1.List(i)

With Me.ListBox3
         'Loop through combobox
        For b = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(b) = qstring Then
                strFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next b
         'Check if we should add item
        If Not strFound Then .AddItem (qstring)
    End With

Next
```

Revised, Thank you for your help sir, I am now wondering why I am receiving this error, Thank you!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOiNI.png)

Comment: Whats not working/what are the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Scripting.Dictionary object which allows unique Keys. You can check if an item exist using the .Exists method.

```
Sub Whatever()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    '1st ListBox
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Not obj.Exists(CStr(ListBox1.List(i))) Then
            obj.Add CStr(ListBox1.List(i)), vbNullString
        End If
    Next

    '2nd ListBox
    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Not obj.Exists(CStr(ListBox2.List(i))) Then
            obj.Add ListBox2.List(i), vbNullString
        End If
    Next

    'add unique list to 3rd ListBox
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In obj.Keys
        ListBox3.AddItem Key
    Next Key
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Credit to @Nathan_Sav for pointing this out. No need to loop to fill the 3rd ListBox.

```
ListBox3.List = obj.Keys()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, please see updated picture, but i can see that this is exactly what I need to be done!

Comment: You can skip the last loop, by just saying `listbox3.list=obj.keys()`

Comment: @Ashley Davies Indeed, we filled the dictionary with Keys but no values. A simple `vbNullString` will do. See updated answer.

Comment: @Kostas K. Thanks both! amazing help and everything is now working! And nathan!